# Excel: Aggregate function combined with IF function

Tags: excel, if-statement, aggregate, extract, criteria

I have an Excel formula I'm having trouble with. I have searched for an answer on Google and YouTube but can't seem to find one.

In Excel I'm using an aggregate function with two criteria. Based on "Location" and "Function" I'm able to extract records from endless rows and columns of data.

I have a dropdown list for both Location and Function. For "Location" I want to be able to choose between:

> No Selection, Amsterdam, Paris, London and Madrid.

For "Function" I want to be able to choose between:

> No Selection, Banker, Banker II and Assistant.

I'm using the following formula:

```
=IF(ROWS(M$2:M2)>$I$6;"";INDEX(source[Name];AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW(source[Name])-ROW(source[#Headers]))/((source[Location]=$I$2)*(source[Function]=$I$3));ROWS(M$2:M2))))
```

I want to be able to extract data based on two criteria but also based on one criteria. That's why I'm using "No Selection". No whenever I choose "No Selection" for Location, I want to be able to extract the data for all the bankers in all of the locations.

The problem I'm having is with the above formula I have to choose two criteria. Whenever I select "No Selection" on one of the dropdown lists it wont extract data.

I know an IF function can be used but I can't get it right. It's a school project I'm working on and my knowledge about Excel is very limited.

Link to an example I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mhsfzv7d63y7rb7/example%281%29.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Why not have two functions, one for one criterion and one for two criteria in an if() statement and choose which one to use...

Comment: My excel knowledge is very limited, I made this sheet with whatever I could learn from google and youtube. I thought this was the best way to extract the data. User10794223 just helped with the formula and it's working perfectly. Thank you for thinking with me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your sample sheet:

```
M2: =IFERROR(INDEX(source,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(((source[[Location]:[Location]]=$I$2)+($I$2="No Selection"))*((source[[Function]:[Function]]=$I$3)+($I$3="No Selection")))*(ROW(source)-ROW(source[#Headers])),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

- Select `M2` and fill down to `M14`
- Select `M2:M14` and fill right.

Note that the `addition` operator is mimicking the `IF` function for each entry in the array.  i.e. `((source[[Location]:[Location]]=$I$2)+($I$2="No Selection"))` will return a `1` if `Location` = either the name in the drop-down, **OR** if the dropdown = `No Selection`

Comment: This is also working perfectly. Thank you so much! I don't know what to say, this was my fist time posting /asking for help on the web and people are so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @Hasmani the fact that your question was clear-cut with usable examples, expected results, actual results, etcetera contributed to your receiving helpful results. In short, your question was in accordance with the guidelines of the news group and made it much easier to provide you with a useful solution.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 1 to each of the aggregate's denominator conditions while ensuring that the denominator never exceeds 1.

```
=IF(ROWS(M$2:M2)>$I$6; ""; INDEX(source[Name]; AGGREGATE(15; 6; (ROW(source[Name])-ROW(source[#Headers]))/SIGN((($I$2="No Selection")+(source[Location]=$I$2))*(($I$3="No Selection")+(source[Function]=$I$3))); ROWS(M$2:M2))))
```

Comment: I was about to make the same suggestion. I noticed that OP would have to make the same change to the Countifs as well - in fact, probably make it into a sumproduct to get the OR conditions. In practice :No Selection" is unlikely to match anything in the source data so arguably Sign isn't necessary, but it is good practice to put it in.

Comment: Yes, there are six of these formulas returning different columns in M2:R2, the COUNTIFS, etc.